# How to test executable Maven Jar file through any web server?

Tags: maven, jar, executable-jar

I just created a maven project and did all the procedure to create a maven build. Then I exported that maven project as the jar file. I want to test the same jar. How could I achieve this with anyone of the web server like TomEE, JBoss?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Why not packagong a war instead of a jar? Then just drop it in the webapps/deploy folder of the server and start